# Knex.js Getting values from comma-separated

Tags: sql, sqlite, knex.js

I have two SQlite3 tables `task` and `tags`

`task` is my master table and `tags` is storing tag names

I store comma-separated values in `task`

Now I want to get `Tag names` with use of a knex.js

table `task`

```
id   task   tags
---------------------
1     abc     1,2,3
2     xyz     3,1
3     apple   2
```

table `tags`

```
id   tag   
------------
1     cold
2     hot     
3     normal
```

Now i want output as below

OUTPUT:

```
id   task   tags
---------------------
1     abc     cold,hot,normal
2     xyz     normal,cold
3     apple   hot
```

I know i will have to use joins but not sure how to actually use it in knex.js. Please do help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that your database is not properly normalised. Instead of having two tables task and tabs, with table tasks containing multiple tag IDs in the column 'tags' you should have three tables; 'tasks', 'tags' and the 'joining' table 'task_tags'. They would store the following data...

**Tasks**

```
id   task 
----------
1     abc 
2     xyz 
3     apple
```

**Tags**

```
id   tag   
------------
1     cold
2     hot     
3     normal
```

**task_tags**

```
task_id tag_id
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         3
3         2
```

Now you can have as many tags as you like (whether or not any tasks use them) and as many tasks as you like (whether or not they use any tags) and you associate a task with it's tags via the task_tags table.

Then to get the result you want you would use the select

```
SELECT 
   tasks.id,
   tasks.task,
   GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag) -- this gives you the csv line eg cold,hot,normal
from tasks
left join task_tags
ON tasks.id = task_tags.task_id
left join tags
on tags.id = task_tags.tag_id
GROUP BY task.id, tags.id
```

see [https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.htm](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)l for explanation of GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: I understand its it custom on SO to accept the answer if it solved the problem. Would you mind doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Your task table should be redesigned to hold one tag per row, not multiple tags in a single row:

```
id          task        tag       
----------  ----------  ----------
1           abc         1         
1           abc         2         
1           abc         3         
2           xyz         3
2           xyz         1         
3           apple       2
```

Then it's easy:

```
SELECT task.id, task.task, group_concat(tags.tag, ',') AS tags
FROM task
JOIN tags ON task.tag = tags.id
GROUP BY task.id, task.task
ORDER BY task.id;
```

which gives

```
id          task        tags           
----------  ----------  ---------------
1           abc         cold,hot,normal
2           xyz         normal,cold    
3           apple       hot
```

A design that follows the rules of relational databases makes life much easier (And the above can be normalized further; see the other answer); while some databases do support array types, sqlite is not one of them. If you insist on keeping your current design, though, there's an ugly hack involving the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension and turning your CSV list of numbers into a JSON array:

```
SELECT task.id, task.task, group_concat(tags.tag, ',') AS tags
FROM task
JOIN json_each('[' || task.tags || ']') AS j
JOIN tags ON tags.id = j.value
GROUP BY task.id, task.task
ORDER BY task.id;
```